# Python 3.6 - Getting names of all videos in a playlist using youtube_dl

Tags: python, playlist, youtube-dl

I have been attempting to make a program using `tkinter` and `youtube_dl` in which the user can download videos easily from YouTube by providing the URL. My program also sorts these videos into playlists for later use. When downloading single videos my app works fine, however I want it to work when the user puts in a link to a playlist rather than a video. All videos download correctly, however, once they are downloaded and my program tries to move them into folders it stops working becuase I can't find all the titles of the videos in the playlist.

Here is my download code:

```
def downloadVideo(event = None):
    ydlOpts = {}
    url = urlEntry.get()
    urlParts = url.split("=")
    nameVid = nameVidEntry.get()
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydlOpts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url) #Gets info about and starts the download
        print(info)
        title = info.get("title", None)
        if nameVid == "":
            nameVid = title.replace("|", "_")
        for filename in os.listdir("."):
            if filename.endswith(urlParts[1] + ".mp4"):
                os.rename(filename, nameVid + ".mp4")
    playlist = playlistEntry.get()
    if playlist != "":
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), playlist)):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), playlist))
        shutil.copy(nameVid + ".mp4", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), playlist))
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "videos")):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "videos"))        
    shutil.move(nameVid + ".mp4", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "videos"))
```

The error that occurs is as follows:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Flight Simulator.mp4' -> 'D:\My Programming\Python\Other Programs\DownloadPlayer\videos\Flight Simulator.mp4'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\My Programming\Python\Other Programs\DownloadPlayer\DownloadPlayer.py", line 31, in downloadVideo
    shutil.move(nameVid + ".mp4", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "videos"))
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 558, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Flight Simulator.mp4'
```

I basically just want this code to work when the user inputs a playlist link as well as a video link. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Flight Simulator is the name of the playlist I am downloadifng, hence why there is no file called Flight Simulator.mp4, as the videos in the playlist are different.

Comment: As a debugging tatic, have you tried printing all the various file and dir paths that are being passed to the `os` and `shutil` functions? There is a chance that one of those calls is not being directed to where you think it is. Maybe also use `os.getcwd()` for the first arg in `shutil.move`.

Comment: Unless I dont understand your comment I don't think that is the problem anyway. I forgot to mention that Flight Simulator.mp4 doesnt exist becuase that is the name of the playlist I am attempting to download.